# ¿Cómo ordeno cantidades desconocidas usando vectores?

Tags: c++, array, punteros, ordenamiento, random

Desarrolle un código en C++ que simule una carrera de 8 autos. En el código cada auto
avanzará, en cada paso, una distancia determinada por una probabilidad aleatoria entre 0 y
1.

• Si la probabilidad es mayor que 0.8 la pista esta libre y avanzará 83 metros

• si está entre 0.6 y 0.8, hay competencia y avanzará 50 metros

• si está entre 0.4 y 0.6, tendrá que frenar un poco y solo avanzará 30 metros

• si está entre 0.2 y 0.4, necesita un control (pit stop) y se detendrá tres pasos

• si es menor que 0.2, le obstruyen el paso y retrocederá 10 metros

Cada avance o retroceso se contará como un paso, con excepción del pit-stop, que son 3
pasos. Ganará el que recorra 300 Kms en la menor cantidad de pasos.

Genere un código que simule la carrera de autos e imprima la lista de los tres primeros
puestos y el número de pasos requerido para ganar. Cada auto debe tener un
nombre.

Por ejemplo, un resultado del código podría ser:

```
Ganador: Mercedes, cantidad de pasos: 11852
2do puesto: McLaren, cantidad de pasos: 11984
3er puesto: Ferrari, cantidad de pasos: 12041
```

Intenté hacerlo con una función void y así me quedó:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void autos(int nombre);

void autos(int nombre, string _auto) {
int m = 0;
    float v;
    do {
        v = (rand() % 9 + 1) / 10.0;
        if (v > 0.8) {
            m += 80;
            nombre += 1;
        }
        else if (v > 0.6 && v < 0.8) {
            m += 50;
            nombre += 1;
        }
        else if (v > 0.4 && v < 0.6) {
            m += 30;
            nombre += 1;
        }
        else if (v > 0.2 && v < 0.4) {
            nombre += 3;
        }
        else {
            m -= 10;
            nombre += 1;
        }
    } while (m < 300000);
    cout << _auto << ", cantidad de pasos: " << nombre << "\n";

}


int main(){
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int mercedes = 0, ford = 0, ferrari = 0, lamborghini = 0, audi = 0, porsche = 0, lexus = 0, toyota = 0;
    string auto1 ="Mercedes", auto2 ="Ford", auto3 ="Ferrari", auto4 ="Lamborghini", auto5 ="Audi", auto6 ="Porsche", auto7 ="Lexus", auto8 ="Toyota";
    autos(mercedes,auto1);
    autos(ford,auto2);
    autos(ferrari,auto3);
    autos(lamborghini,auto4);
    autos(audi,auto5);
    autos(porsche,auto6);
    autos(lexus,auto7);
    autos(toyota,auto8);
}
```

Sin embargo, en el output tengo que ordenar la cantidad de pasos. Entonces, ¿cuál sería un método para ordenar valores aleatorios? ¿debería guardarlos en un vector?

Comment: Responder a esta pregunta en su estado sería hacerte los deberes. Intenta resolver el problema por tu cuenta y haz preguntas concretas sobre los problemas que vayas teniendo

Comment: Una disculpa por no adjuntar mi código, fue un error de edición.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (v > 0.8) {
    m += 80;
    nombre += 1;
}
else if (v > 0.6 && v < 0.8) {
```

¿Y si da la casualidad que `v == 0.8`? En ese caso, dado no se va a cumplir `v > 0.8` y tampoco se cumple que `v<0.8` ... al final entrará por el último `else` y el coche retrocederá 10 pasos. Deberías decidir cual de las dos condiciones se queda con el valor que hace de frontera.

Por otro lado, la gracia de las cadenas `if-else if` es que el código solo puede tomar uno de los múltiples caminos que están disponibles. Es decir, si el código llega al primer `else if` es porque no se ha cumplido la condición del `if` inicial.

Una posible manera de dejar la secuencia de condicionales podría ser:

```
if (v > 0.8) {
    m += 80;
    nombre += 1;
}
else if (v > 0.6) {
    m += 50;
    nombre += 1;
}
else if (v > 0.4) {
    m += 30;
    nombre += 1;
}
else if (v > 0.2) {
    nombre += 3;
}
else {
    m -= 10;
    nombre += 1;
}
```

Nota que ahora la secuencia queda más limpia

Otro aspecto a mejorar de esa función es el tema de los nombres de las variables. Si ya `m` no es un nombre que signifique absolutamente nada, `nombre` además da una idea equivocada acerca de la información almacenada por esta variable.

Intenta que los diferentes elementos del lenguaje (estructuras, funciones, variables, alias, ...) tengan nombres que den una idea de la función que cumplen éstos en el código. Esta práctica permitirá tener código más legible y muchos errores se encontrarán solos.

Y bueno, respondiendo ya a tus dudas:

> ¿cuál sería un método para ordenar valores aleatorios?

Pues lo primero sería idear un mecanismo para que la función pudiese devolver el número de pasos que ha tenido que dar el coche para llegar a la meta.

Tu función actualmetne recibe un entero **que no sirve para nada**

```
void autos(int nombre, string _auto) {
//             ~~~~~~ <<---
```

Date cuenta que `nombre` no es ni un puntero ni una referencia, luego a `autos` le llegará **una copia** del valor o variable que le pases durante la llamada a la función. Al ser `nombre` una copia de otro valor, los cambios que hagas sobre esta variable no tendrán repercusión fuera de la función.

Por otro lado, dado que el valor final de `nombres` depende únicamente de la ejecución de dicha función y no de condiciones externas, lo suyo sería usar el `return`.

Por otro lado, no veo la necesidad de llamar a `cout` dentro de `autos`. Si eliminamos esta llamada ya no necesitamos tampoco el parámetro `_auto`:

```
int calcular_pasos()
{
    int distancia = 0;
    int pasos = 0;
    do {
        float v = (rand() % 9 + 1) / 10.0;
        if (v > 0.8) {
            distancia += 80;
            pasos++;
        }
        else if (v > 0.6 && v < 0.8) {
            distancia += 50;
            pasos++;
        }
        else if (v > 0.4 && v < 0.6) {
            distancia += 30;
            pasos++;
        }
        else if (v > 0.2 && v < 0.4) {
            pasos += 3;
        }
        else {
            distancia -= 10;
            pasos++;
        }
    } while (distancia < 300000);

    return pasos;
}
```

Por otro lado, el generador de números aleatorios no está siendo tratado de forma correcta. Se supone que el programa debería generar números en el rango 0..1, pero tu programa **no genera** valores extremo (no genera 0.0 ni 1.0), por lo que las probabilidades arrojadas por tu programa no son equiprobables:

| Rango | Posibles valores | Nº de valores | Probabilidad esperada | Probabilidad real |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `v > 0.8` | 0.9 | 1 | 20% | 11% |
| `v > 0.6` | 0.7 - 0.8 | 2 | 20% | 22% |
| `v > 0.4` | 0.6 - 0.5 | 2 | 20% | 22% |
| `v > 0.2` | 0.4 - 0.3 | 2 | 20% | 22% |
| `else` | 0.2 - 0.1 | 2 | 20% | 22% |

Lo cierto es que la probabilidad real no es exactamente esta porque `rand()` no genera números en un rango múltiplo de 10. El rango viene dado por una base 2, la operación `rand() % 9` no genera resultados equiprobables.

Podrías rediseñar tu fórmula, pero casi va a ser más sencillo utilizar el generador de números aleatorios propio de C++. Para hacer uso de este mecanismo tienes que importar la librería `random`.

La inicialización del generador quedaría así:

```
std::random_device seed;
std::mt19937 rnd(seed());
std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(0.0, 1.0);
```

Parece un poco complicado pero es muy sencillo:

- `seed` es un generador de números aleatorios basado en hardware. Este generador es el mejor generando números aleatorios peeero tiene como pega que es un poco lento. Se usa para inicializar un generador más rápido
- `rnd` es otro generador de números aleatorios. Este generador es mucho más rápido generando secuencias aleatorias pero es *menos aleatorio*, es decir, sus secuencias son predecibles a partir de la semilla inicial. La semilla inicial se obtiene de `seed`
- `dist` es una utilidad que recibe un número aleatorio y le aplica una transformación para que la distribución de los resultados sea la deseada. En este caso `dist` va a devolver números en coma flotante distribuidos de forma uniforme en el intervalo `[0, 1)`. La librería `random` tiene otras utilidades para obtener distribuciones diferentes, pero la que necesitas ahora mismo es esta.

Bien, una vez inicializada la generación de números aleatorios ya solo queda usarla:

```
float v = dist(rng);
```

Todo esto aplicado a tu función la dejaría así:

```
int calcular_pasos()
{
    std::random_device seed;
    std::mt19937 rnd(seed());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(0.0, 1.0);

    int distancia = 0;
    int pasos = 0;
    do {
        float v = dist(rnd);
        if (v > 0.8) {
            distancia += 80;
            pasos++;
        }
        else if (v > 0.6 && v < 0.8) {
            distancia += 50;
            pasos++;
        }
        else if (v > 0.4 && v < 0.6) {
            distancia += 30;
            pasos++;
        }
        else if (v > 0.2 && v < 0.4) {
            pasos += 3;
        }
        else {
            distancia -= 10;
            pasos++;
        }
    } while (distancia < 300000);

    return pasos;
}
```

Vale, la función ya estaría arreglada. Ahora tienes que recoger los resultados de cada vehículo y ordenar los resultados. Efectivamente para esto necesitas un array (o una lista).

Dado que ahora tienes 2 datos de cada vehículo

- Nombre
- Nº de pasos

Lo suyo sería crear una estructura para que estos valores vayan siempre juntos:

```
struct Vehiculo
{
    std::string nombre;
    int num_pasos = 0;
};
```

Si no quieres crear una estructura también podrías usar un `std::pair` o un `std::tuple`.

Ya tienes la estructura, ahora podrías crear el array:

```
Vehiculo vehiculos[] = { { "Mercedes" }, { "Ford" }, { "Ferrari" }, { "Lamborghini" }, { "Audi" }, { "Porsche" }, { "Lexus" }, { "Toyota" } };
```

Date cuenta de que como ya le hemos dado un valor inicial a `num_pasos` ya no es necesario dar ese valor explícitamente a cada elemento del array.

Una vez el array ya está creado calculamos el número de pasos:

```
for (Vehiculo & vehiculo : vehiculos)
{
    vehiculo.num_pasos = calcular_pasos();
}
```

Ahora tienes que ordenar el array. Yo voy a usar la función `sort`:

```
std::sort(std::begin(vehiculos), std::end(vehiculos),
          [](Vehiculo const& a, Vehiculo const& b) { return a.num_pasos < b.num_pasos; });
```

La función `sort` la configuro con una función `lambda`. Si no te gustan / no te dejan usar este tipo de funciones, puedes usar una función a la vieja usanza:

```
bool ordenar_por_pasos(Vehiculo const& a, Vehiculo const& b)
{
    return a.num_pasos < b.num_pasos;
}

std::sort(std::begin(vehiculos), std::end(vehiculos), ordenar_por_pasos);
```

Y ya estaría, ya tendrías el array ordenado de forma descendente. Ya solo queda presentarlo:

```
for (Vehiculo & vehiculo : vehiculos)
{
    std::cout << std::setw(15) << std::left << vehiculo.nombre << vehiculo.num_pasos << '\n';
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sciZV9xXeoqvbZPT)